# search tweet from tweet id in elasticsearch by custom id

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have been trying to search for the particular tweet through custom id in Kibana, my elasticsearch repo has the timeline json of a multiple accounts. I have tried so much formats but could not get it.

```
GET twitter/tweet/_search
{
   "query":{
      "term":{"id":"850330838709489700"}
   }
}
```

following is the document sample.

```
{
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "AVwvzcZROQ98HXQdQAPR",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "contributors": null,
          "truncated": false,
          "text": """"@zee_alam: Jiyoo. https://.../5qojZMzt4t" 
Don't mind but this is bullshit """,
          "is_quote_status": false,
          "in_reply_to_status_id": 833583764513181700,
          "id": 833609664973635600,
          "favorite_count": 1,
          "source": """<a href="http://www.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Windows Phone</a>""",
          "retweeted": false,
          "coordinates": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              73.07080201,
              33.64006041
            ]
          },
          "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [
              {
                "id": 263167083,
                "indices": [
                  1,
                  10
                ],
                "id_str": "263167083",
                "screen_name": "zee_alam",
                "name": "Zee Shan Alam"
              }
            ],
            "hashtags": [],
            "urls": [
              {
                "url": "https://xxxxqojZMzt4t",
                "indices": [
                  19,
                  42
                ],
                "expanded_url": "http://xxxxme/6AFOzdQj2",
                "display_url": "fb.me/6AFOzdQj2"
              }
            ]
          },
          "in_reply_to_screen_name": "zee_alam",
          "in_reply_to_user_id": 263167083,
          "retweet_count": 0,
          "id_str": "833609664973635584",
          "favorited": false,
          "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false,
            "has_extended_profile": true,
            "profile_use_background_image": false,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "id": 1217815686,
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme8/bg.gif",
            "verified": false,
            "translator_type": "none",
            "profile_text_color": "000000",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/838740477230911488/B5ynFwDD_normal.jpg",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
            "entities": {
              "url": {
                "urls": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://xxxxbQ6KljtBK",
                    "indices": [
                      0,
                      23
                    ],
                    "expanded_url": "https://etabz.blogspot.com",
                    "display_url": "etabz.blogspot.com"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "description": {
                "urls": []
              }
            },
            "followers_count": 88,
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
            "id_str": "1217815686",
            "profile_background_color": "000000",
            "listed_count": 1,
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "utc_offset": 18000,
            "statuses_count": 295,
            "description": "Bi-Tri- quardi | Taekwando & Parkour freak && Climber | Sagittarius 10 |  Lucky  13 | Future is just Unexpected so cheers | Stay happy",
            "friends_count": 157,
            "location": "Islamabd, Pakistan.",
            "profile_link_color": "1B95E0",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/838740477230911488/B5ynFwDD_normal.jpg",
            "following": true,
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1217815686/1468083529",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme8/bg.gif",
            "screen_name": "shaamuji",
            "lang": "en",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "favourites_count": 169,
            "name": "Ehtisham ullah",
            "notifications": false,
            "url": "https:/xxxxbQ6KljtBK",
            "created_at": "Mon Feb 25 10:08:09 +0000 2013",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "time_zone": "Karachi",
            "protected": false,
            "default_profile": false,
            "is_translator": false
          },
          "geo": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              33.64006041,
              73.07080201
            ]
          },
          "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "263167083",
          "possibly_sensitive": false,
          "lang": "en",
          "created_at": "Mon Feb 20 09:30:06 +0000 2017",
          "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "833583764513181697",
          "place": {
            "country_code": "PK",
            "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/008a844c675a661b.json",
            "country": "Pakistan",
            "place_type": "city",
            "bounding_box": {
              "type": "Polygon",
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  [
                    72.952919,
                    33.53611
                  ],
                  [
                    73.122971,
                    33.53611
                  ],
                  [
                    73.122971,
                    33.670082
                  ],
                  [
                    72.952919,
                    33.670082
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            },
            "contained_within": [],
            "full_name": "Rawalpindi, Pakistan",
            "attributes": {},
            "id": "008a844c675a661b",
            "name": "Rawalpindi"
          }
        }
      }
```

[see the result displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMSqu.png)

Comment: Can you share the document that is supposed to match?

Comment: @Val I have updated the question.

Comment: The `id` field of that document is different: `833609664973635600` vs `850330838709489700 `

Comment: This is a sample document but the point is I am  not able to search for the document by id even if i put 833609664973635600 instead of 833609664973635600.

Comment: it's probably related to you mapping. can you share your mapping ? May be doing exact term search over an "analyzed" field.

Comment: The id field is both searchable as well as analyzed.

Comment: @Val Please consider the issue I am not able to search the id field there are multiple files in the db and search query doesn't return any of them even if the id matches.

Comment: I have solved the issue and it is because Kibana displays the values that have been round off after 16th digit where the value in elasticsearch database is exact value. So that mean I was comparing it with wrong key when I compared it with the actual key it gives me the result. that was 850330838709489627. [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-id-with-long-type-changes-the-actual-value/87473) is the detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved as the problem was with the representation of the id in kibana. I was comparing with the values that was rounded off where as the original value in elasticsearch was different. [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-id-with-long-type-changes-the-actual-value/87473) is the detail